# Progress bar form fill out with jquery

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I am trying to create a progress bar that increases as a form is being filled out.  For example if I had 5 inputs.  Each input would need to be filled out to get to 100%  My goal is to activate a button once the form reaches 100%.

My thought process was to do a bunch of if blank make it a value of 0 but if not then it gets a value of 10, or some arbitrary number.

Then I would just add up those values to complete the progress bar.

I am not sure how to set up the values so that I can add them up or this is even the right way to go.  I am not sure where to go with it.  Here is the code:

```
<form>
One<input id="1" type="name" name="name"><br />
Two<input id="2" type="name" name="name"><br />
Three<input id="3" type="name" name="else"><br />
Four<input id="4" type="name" name="name"><br />
Five<input id="5" type="name" name="name"><br />

</form>


<div id="progressbar"></div>

$(function() {
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: 37
});

});

$(function(){
 if ( $('#1').val() == '' ){value == 0};
 } else {
     value == 10;  };
if ( $('#2').val() == '' ){value == 0};
 } else {
     value == 10;  };
if ( $('#3').val() == '' ){value == 0};
 } else {
     value == 10;  };
if ( $('#4').val() == '' ){value == 0};
 } else {
     value == 10;  };
if ( $('#5').val() == '' ){value == 0};
 } else {
     value == 10;  };
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you considered using jqueryui?  There's [a progress bar there](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/).

Comment: Yeah that is where I started.

Comment: Sorry, I should pay attention more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form>
One<input id="1" type="name" name="name" class='moo'><br />
Two<input id="2" type="name" name="name" class='moo'><br />
Three<input id="3" type="name" name="else" class='moo'><br />
Four<input id="4" type="name" name="name" class='moo'><br />
Five<input id="5" type="name" name="name" class='moo'><br />
</form>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: 0
});

$(".moo").change(function() {
    var pbVal = 0;
    if ($("#1").val().length > 0) pbVal += 20;
    if ($("#2").val().length > 0) pbVal += 20;
    if ($("#3").val().length > 0) pbVal += 20;
    if ($("#4").val().length > 0) pbVal += 20;
    if ($("#5").val().length > 0) pbVal += 20;
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( "option", "value", pbVal );
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: I like this approach, but personally I think the pbVal should be encoded on the HTML element as a data-pbValue attribute, not in the Javascript. Javascript should be responsible for doing the adding, not for knowing what values to add. If you do that then you can loop over the individual elements and add them up with the same code to get the total for the progress bar.

Comment: @Jazzepi  do you have an example of this?

Comment: @TimCooley Added an answer extending Dan's with the approach I mentioned. I think it's a lot more flexible. I also got rid of the moo class, you don't need to add that extra class css.

Answer (score 6):

HTML:

```
<form>
One<input id="1" type="name" name="name" data-pbVal="60"><br />
Two<input id="2" type="name" name="name" data-pbVal="5"><br />
Three<input id="3" type="name" name="name" data-pbVal="5"><br />
Four<input id="4" type="name" name="name" data-pbVal="0"><br />
Five<input id="5" type="name" name="name" data-pbVal="30"><br />
</form>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: 0
});

//Register this function to fire whenever a value changes in one of the input elements
$("form input").change(function() {
    var pbVal = 0;
    //For each input element, count the value on the data-pbVal element and add it to the total
    $("form input").each(function(index) {
        if($(this).val().length > 0) {
            pbVal += $(this).data('pbVal');
        }
    });
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( "option", "value", pbVal );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I planned to add more on to the pbVal so i think this one will work nicely. Thanks agian for the help!

Comment: @TimCooley No problem. Happy to help. Doing short scripts in JQuery is actually pretty fun. BTW I hope you recognize what I'm trying to do by shifting the data into the HTML as opposed to storing it in Javascript. If you store some structured data in HTML, and then some in Javascript, then you end up having to look at both things when changing one or the other. Really you want the responsibilities in one place so the coupling is looser, so if you need to modify the number of elements in the input the Javascript doesn't break.