# Progress bar indicating form completion in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, user-interface, progress-bar

I'm working on a progress bar using the `progress` element that increases as the user completes fields in a lengthy form. I found [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773369/progress-bar-form-fill-out-with-jquery) which was helpful in getting some baseline functionality using a `data-*` attribute, but my form has a "Save Progress" feature that will save any entered field information to the browser's local storage to be retrieved later. Thus, in the event that a user returns to the form with saved data, I'd like the bar to reflect that level of progress.

Here's what is working thus far- sample markup using the data-attribute `data-prog` for a form field:

```
<!-- FORM - SAMPLE FIELD -->
<div id="form">
<div class="field-group required">
   <label for="mgd_org_name">Organization Name:</label>
   <div>
      <input id="mgd_org_name" type="text" name="mgd_org_name" placeholder="Please enter your organization's name" required data-prog="6">
   </div>
</div>
</form>

<!-- Progress bar -->
<div id="form-progress">
    <p>Form Progress</p>
    <progress max="100" value="0" id="progress"></progress>
</div>
```

And the jQuery thus far:

```
$(function() {
    // get all form inputs w/ data-prog values
    var inputs = $('#dossier-form').find('input[data-prog], textarea[data-prog]');
    var progBar = $('#progress');
    var progVal = 0;

    $(inputs).change(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            progVal += $(this).data('prog');
            progBar.attr('value', progVal);
        }
    });

});
```

In this way, each field has a `data-prog` value that will be added to the `progVal` and reflected in the progress bar level. What I'm having trouble with is loading an *initial* value for any form fields that might already be filled on load—thus, I would need to find all fields that have a value entered, add the associated `data-prog` values, and initially load that value into the progress bar. I would also like to accordingly *decrease* the progress value in the event that a field is cleared.

For the initial load, I've been trying something like the following (not working):

```
var inputsSaved = $(inputs).val();
if($(inputsSaved).length > 0) {
    progVal = $(inputs).data('prog');
    console.log('has existing progress');
} else {
    progVal = 0;
    console.log('does not have existing progress');
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to find the fields with text entered on load and grab the associated prog values nor how to decrease the value accordingly if a field is cleared. Any assistance here is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's a non-trivial task. Why not settle with a fake progress, or an indefinite progress?

Comment: @IvanRubinson can you elaborate on what you mean by fake/indefinite progress? Also, is there not a way to see which fields have data entered on load, and add up the respective `data-prog` values? That's the part I'm most concerned about.

Comment: **1)** Unless you really want to assign different progress percentage to each input... Why not just count how many are filled divided by the total? **2)** Then localStorage can be used to fill previously entered values... Sure.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette would you mind posting an answer showing that solution? The idea was to assign higher values to questions that take more effort, but I might scrap that approach and try what you've suggested.

Comment: Okay I see about the "effort" aspect... I have an idea allowing you to keep that. Give me a couple minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `inputs` selector can be replaced by:

```
var inputs = $('#dossier-form [data-prog]');
```

Then, `$(inputs).change(...`, `inputs` already is a jQuery object. No need to wrap it with `$()`.

You had the progress update function correct. I just placed it in a named function to be able to call it from different places in code (and avoid duplicate code).

I added the `localStorage` save and retreive...

```
$(function() {

  // get all form inputs w/ data-prog values
  var inputs = $('#dossier-form [data-prog]');
  var progBar = $('#progress');
  var progVal = 0;

  // Establish the "dificulty unit" base.
  var totalDifficulty = 0;
  inputs.each(function(){
    totalDifficulty += $(this).data('prog');
  });

  var difficultyUnit = 100/totalDifficulty;

  // Update progressbar
  function updateProgress(el){
    progVal += parseFloat($(el).data('prog')) * difficultyUnit;
    progBar.val(progVal);
  }

  // LocalStorage on load
  inputs.each(function(){
    var value = localStorage.getItem(this.id);
    if(value !=null && value !=""){
      $(this).val(value);
      updateProgress(this);
    }
  });  // End load from LocalStorage

  // Blur handler to save user inputs
  inputs.on("blur",function(){
    // Reset the progress
    progVal = 0;
    progBar.val(progVal);

    // Loop through all inputs for progress
    inputs.each(function(){
      if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        updateProgress(this);
      }

      // LocalStorage
      localStorage.setItem(this.id,this.value);
    });
  });  // End on blur

});  // End ready
```

`localStorage` isn't allowed in the SO snippets... So have a look at this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/vzOOaM?editors=1011).

---

So you can now give some "difficulty level" without worring about the total obtained by all the `data-prog` to be 100. Just give an arbitrary number you feel like. ;)

Comment: lol... I think I made a bit too much here... Your question got my interest! ;) Tell me if it fits your needs!

Comment: Wow, this is phenomenal! Thank you- I'll try this as well. I would imagine this will help others down the road as well.

Comment: Quick question- I already have buttons w/ functions to save form data to local storage and clear, do you think I can still use your function as is without any issues related to local storage? Thanks again- you should make this into a plugin!

Comment: I don't know... Try it! In my code above, it's an onload "filler" and a blur handler. So if you have a button to save already, just remove the blur handler.

Comment: My point of interest was the "difficulty level" concept... So you can have, for example, just 5 levels, like 1=easy to fill and 5=hard. Then have the input amount you need in the form without caring about the total. ;) So you can add one input on the fly or change the difficulty as you feel.

Comment: Using the `blur` event and adding to the total, if I blur a field twice, won't it get counted twice? And if I clear a field, the total is not going to go down.

Comment: You are right @BenWest. Thanks for mentionning. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you always add up the progress from scratch, you can do the same thing in both cases.

```
$(function() {

    // get all form inputs w/ data-prog values
    var inputs = $('#dossier-form').find('input[data-prog], textarea[data-prog]');
    var progBar = $('#progress');

    function update () {
        var progVal = 0;
        inputs.each( function () {
            if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
                progVal += Number( $(this).data('prog') );
            }
        })
        progBar.attr('value', progVal);
    }

    inputs.change( update );

    // Fill in fields from localStorage, then:
    update();

});
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a shot.